# Each Line in Different Colour after Reflection

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, plot-themes

The following code gives me a reflection pattern inside a circular billiard from time, $t=0$ to $t=10$. The figure below shows all the rays are in a single colour after reflection. However, I want them to be in different colours. **The earliest should be the faintest, and the latest should be the darkest, or they may follow `"AvocadoColors"`, or `"SolarColors"`, or `"SiennaTones"`, or `"ValentineTones"` Color Schemes.**

```
Billiard[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;

Traj[{x0_, y0_}, {vx0_, vy0_}, tmax_] := 
 Module[{NV, nvec, refV}, 
  NV = Grad[Billiard[xB, yB], {xB, yB}]/
   Norm[Grad[Billiard[xB, yB], {xB, yB}]];
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == vx[t], y'[t] == vy[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
    vx[0] == vx0, vy[0] == vy0, 
    WhenEvent[
     Billiard[x[t], y[t]] == 
      1, {nvec = (NV /. xB -> x[t] /. yB -> y[t]);
      refV = {vx[t], vy[t]} - 2*({vx[t], vy[t]}.nvec) nvec;
      {vx[t], vy[t]} -> refV}]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1/1000, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}, 
   MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], DiscreteVariables -> {vx, vy}]]
sols = Traj[{-0.5, 0}, {2, 1}, 50];

CB = RegionPlot[Billiard[x, y] <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> 500];
CB1 = Show[CB, 
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sols], {t, 1, 10}]]
```

[image]

> How should I modify the existing code to get the desired result?

Please help me out, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `ColorData` with `{"AvocadoColors", "Reverse"}` can make `The earliest should be the faintest, and the latest should be the darkest`.

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sols], {t, 0, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", "Reverse"}][#3] &), 
 Prolog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[{-.5, 0}], CB[[1]]}, 
 PlotRange -> 1]
```

[image]

- Or `Sow` and `Reap` all the reflect times so that get all the piecewise functions and color them by `Blend[{Yellow, Blue}, i/Length@times]]` or  `ColorData["AvocadoColors"] /@ Subdivide[1, 0, Length@times]`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Billiard[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
Traj[{x0_, y0_}, {vx0_, vy0_}, tmax_] := 
 Module[{NV, nvec, refV}, 
  NV = Grad[Billiard[xB, yB], {xB, yB}]/
    Norm[Grad[Billiard[xB, yB], {xB, yB}]];
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == vx[t], y'[t] == vy[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
    vx[0] == vx0, vy[0] == vy0, 
    WhenEvent[
     Billiard[x[t], y[t]] == 
      1, {nvec = (NV /. xB -> x[t] /. yB -> y[t]);
      refV = {vx[t], vy[t]} - 2*({vx[t], vy[t]} . nvec)  nvec;
      {vx[t], vy[t]} -> refV, Sow@t}]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1/1000, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}, 
   MaxSteps -> ∞, DiscreteVariables -> {vx, vy}]]
sols = Traj[{-0.5, 0}, {2, 1}, 5] // Reap;
times = Join[{0}, sols[[2, 1]]];
CB = RegionPlot[Billiard[x, y] <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> 500];
Show[Table[
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sols[[1]]], {t, times[[i]], 
    times[[i + 1]]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blend[{Yellow, Blue}, i/Length@times]], {i, 1, 
   Length@times - 1}], PlotRange -> 1]

colors = ColorData["AvocadoColors"] /@ Subdivide[1, 0, Length@times];
Show[Table[
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sols[[1]]], {t, times[[i]], 
    times[[i + 1]]}, PlotStyle -> colors[[i]]], {i, 1, 
   Length@times - 1}], PlotRange -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
pts = First @ Cases[ParametricPlot[
     Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sols[[1]]], {t, 0, 10}], Line[x_] :> x, 
    All];

pieces =  BlockMap[pts[[Span @@ #]] &, Join[{1}, Mean /@ #, {-1}] & @ 
     SequencePosition[pts, 
       {a : {_, _}, b : {_, _}, c : {_, _}} /; (Norm[a] <= Norm[b] >= Norm[c])],
   2, 1];


coloredPieces = MapIndexed[
 {ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", {Length @ pieces, 1}}] @ #2[[1]], Line @ #} &] @ 
 pieces;

Show[CB, Graphics @ coloredPieces]
```

[image]

**Update:** Use the option `DisplayFunction` to replace the `Line` primitive with colored segments:

```
displayFunction[cs_String : "AvocadoColors"] := 
 ReplaceAll[Line[x_] :> 
  Module[{segs = BlockMap[Line @ x[[Span @@ #]] &, 
       Join[{1}, #, {-1}] & @ Map[Mean] @
         SequencePosition[x, {a : {_, _}, b : {_, _}, 
            c : {_, _}} /; (Norm[a] <= Norm[b] >= Norm[c])], 2, 1]}, 
    MapIndexed[{ColorData[{cs, {Length @ segs, 1}}] @ #2[[1]], #} &]@segs]]


ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sols[[1]]], {t, 0, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> 1, DisplayFunction -> displayFunction[]]
```

[image]

Use `DisplayFunction -> displayFunction["SolarColors"]` to get

[image]